# DirectX9 texture shows up distorted

Tags: c++, drawing, video-streaming, directx, directx-9

For some reason on machines that only **conditionally** (`D3DPTEXTURECAPS_NONPOW2CONDITIONAL`) supports the "non power of two" (NONPOW2) textures I'm getting this kind of image distortion:

[image]

(On machines that fully supports NONPOW2 textures everything works fine.)

This is a 1280x720 resolution RGB24 (`D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8`).

I know there are four rules when dealing with conditionally supported textures:

1.**The texture addressing mode for the texture stage is set to D3DTADDRESS_CLAMP.**

`mpDevice->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_ADDRESSU, D3DTADDRESS_CLAMP);`

`mpDevice->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_ADDRESSV, D3DTADDRESS_CLAMP);`

`mpDevice->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_ADDRESSW, D3DTADDRESS_CLAMP);`

2.**Texture wrapping for the texture stage is disabled (D3DRS_WRAP n set to 0).**

`mpDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_WRAP0, 0);`

3.**Mipmapping is not in use (use magnification filter only).**

`mpDevice->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MIPFILTER, D3DTEXF_NONE);`

4.**Texture formats must not be D3DFMT_DXT1 through D3DFMT_DXT5.**

I'm using `D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8`...

Texture is created like this:

`mpDevice->CreateTexture(width, height, 1, D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC, D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &pTexture, nullptr);`

And updated like this:

```
D3DLOCKED_RECT lockedRect;

pTexture->LockRect(0, &lockedRect, nullptr, D3DLOCK_DISCARD);

// const IppiSize roiSize = { width, height };

// ippiCopy_8u_C3AC4R((Ipp8u*) pPixels, width * 3, (Ipp8u*) lockedRect.pBits, width * 4, roiSize);  // RGB to RGBA
// ippiCopy_8u_AC4C3R((Ipp8u*) pPixels, width * 4, (Ipp8u*) lockedRect.pBits, width * 3, roiSize);  // RGBA to RGB

// TEMP.
      unsigned char* pDst = (unsigned char*) lockedRect.pBits;
const unsigned char* pSrc = pPixels;

for (int k = 0; k < width; k++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
   {
      pDst[0] = pSrc[0];
      pDst[1] = pSrc[1];
      pDst[2] = pSrc[2];
      pDst[3] = 255;

      pDst += 4;
      pSrc += 3;
   }
}

pTexture->UnlockRect(0);
```

Does anyone had any similar problem? Or have any idea on what is going on?

Maybe there's something wrong with the RGB data itself?

Thanks.

Comment: One problem (maybe the only one) is that you're not taking account of the pitch in `D3DLOCKED_RECT` and are assuming that rows are not padded. It's quite likely that they are padded to the next power-of-two size, so your loading code would be wrong.

Comment: Thanks Roger for a hint! In `ippiCopy_8u_C3AC4R` I've changed from `width * 4` to `lockedRect.Pitch` and everything works fine now.

Comment: Excellent - glad you got it sorted ....